# Passing value to Child Component is updating only once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue application, I have a list of months in my parent component like this-

[image]

When clicking on any month, I would like to pass its id to the child component named `timeComponent`. Below is the code.

**Parent Component-**

```
<template>
    <div class="content container-fluid" id="prayer_time">        
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header p-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item" v-for="(month, index) in months" :key="index">
                            <a class="nav-link" v-on:click="monthId(index + 1)">
                                {{ month }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.card-header -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <div v-if="prayertimeshow">
            <timeComponent :month_id=month_id :mosque_id=this.mosque_id />        
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import timeComponent from './TimeComponent.vue';
    export default {
        props: ['mosque_id'],
        components: {
            timeComponent
        },
        data(){
            return {
                month_id: '',
                prayertimeshow: '',
                months : ['January', 'February', 'March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
            }
        },
        methods:{
            monthId(event) { 
                this.month_id = event; 
                this.prayertimeshow = true;   
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click on any month for the first time, the `month_id` value is passed to the child component perfectly.
But it is not working when I click on another month for the second time.

In the child component, I am accessing the prop value like this-

```
<script>     
       export default {         
            props: ['month_id'],         
            created: function () {
              console.log(this.month_id);  
            }    
       }
 
</script>
```

Is it the correct way to do this?

Comment: I tried your code in the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-shadow-zpvtfd?file=/src/App.vue. Everything is working fine, not sure what the issue is. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. I am trying to catch the value at Child component in this way. `<script>
    export default {
        props: ['month_id'],
        created: function () {
            console.log(this.month_id);
        }
    }
</script>`. Is it the correct way ? Thanks.

Comment: The created hook will only be called once. So you won't get a console every time month_id changes. Instead of a console try displaying month_id in the template. like-
`<template>
  <div>{{ month_id }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["month_id"],
};
</script>`

Comment: In that way, you can check if your prop is updating correctly in the child component.

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. Your solution is working. I have a `method` child component. How can I run the method when click on month name. I am trying like this. `created: function () {
            this.getTime();
        }`

Comment: use watcher for this. Apply watch on prop, month_id, and call the function inside watcher. for reference you can check same here- https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-shadow-zpvtfd?file=/src/TimeComponent.vue

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. Could you please provide some sample code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that created hook runs only once when the child component has been created.
The better approach to check the updated prop value in the child is to use a [watch hook](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html).

You can check the update in month_id like this-

Child Component-

```
<template>
  <div>{{ month_id }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["month_id"],

  watch: {
    month_id(newVal, oldVal) {
      // newVal = updated month_id
      this.getTime(newVal);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    getTime(input) {
      console.log(input);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Neha Soni. How can I set a default value for the props so that at the time of loading it work ?

Comment: You can set the default value of it like this- props: { month_id: { default: 1 } }. To read more about props- https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation